# Auto-growing of QTreeWidget(or QTableWidget)

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I placed QTreeWidget into QVBoxLayout.

```
self._tree = QTreeWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(self._some_other_widget)
layout.addWidget(self._tree)
layout.addStretch()
self.setLayout(layout)
```

All nodes in this tree widget are always expanded.
I would like to create this tree widget with minimal height (for example, for one row/item). When new items are added this tree widget also grows to show all items. How can this be done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [`self._tree.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop)?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions:

1. Use `self._tree.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToC‌​ontents)`. Thank you for this, G.M.
2. I have also found another solution:

   ```
   def sizeHint(self):
       return self._sizeHint()

   def minimumSizeHint(self):
       return self._sizeHint()

   def _sizeHint(self):
       sh = super().sizeHint()
       if self._item_count > 0:
           return QSize(sh.width(), self.sizeHintForRow(0) * self._item_count)
       else:
           return QSize(sh.width(), 40)
   ```